# Issue with YOLOv5 TensorFlow inference - Unable to detect persons in images

Tags: tensorflow, object, detection, tensorflow-lite, yolov5

I am currently facing an issue with the YOLOv5 model in TensorFlow when performing inference on images. The model, "personK1.tflite," is specifically designed to detect persons. However, when I run the inference code, it doesn't detect any persons in the test images, even though the images contain multiple persons.

Here is a simplified version of my inference code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def draw_bounding_boxes(image, bounding_boxes, class_labels, threshold):
    
    for i, bbox in enumerate(bounding_boxes):
        confidence=class_labels[i][0]
        if confidence > 0.5:  # Check if class label exceeds threshold
            category=class_labels[i][1]
            print(category)
            x_center, y_center, width, height = bbox
            image_width = image.shape[1]
            image_height = image.shape[0]
            xmin = int((x_center - (width / 2)) * image_width)
            ymin = int((y_center - (height / 2)) * image_height)
            xmax = int((x_center + (width / 2)) * image_width)
            ymax = int((y_center + (height / 2)) * image_height)
            print(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)
            cv2.rectangle(image, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(image, 'Person', (xmin, ymin - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    return image

# Load TFLite model
model_path = 'personK1.tflite'
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output details
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']  # Get the input shape
input_image = cv2.imread('input_image.jpg')
# Resize the image to match the input shape of the model
resized_image = cv2.resize(input_image, (input_shape[1], input_shape[2]))
# Normalize the pixel values to be in the range [0, 1]
normalized_image = resized_image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
# Expand dimensions to create a batch of size 1
input_data = np.expand_dims(normalized_image, axis=0)
# Set the input tensor of the model
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
# Invoke the interpreter to perform inference
interpreter.invoke()
# Get the output tensor
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
# Process the output to obtain the bounding boxes and class labels
bounding_boxes = output_data[:, :, :4]
class_labels = output_data[:, :, 4:]
output_image = draw_bounding_boxes(input_image, bounding_boxes[0], class_labels[0], 0.5)

# Display the image with bounding boxes
cv2.imshow('Output Image', output_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have double-checked the code and the input details of the model, but I couldn't find any obvious issues. The draw_bounding_boxes function seems fine, and the input image is preprocessed correctly.

I compared my code with a similar implementation using the Ultralytics YOLOv5 library, and their code successfully detects persons in the same images. So, it seems like there might be something specific to my code or the model itself.

```
import torch

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', 'personK1-fp16.tflite')  # custom trained model
im = 'input_image.jpg'  # file, Path, PIL.Image, OpenCV, nparray, list
results = model(im)  # inference
results.show()  # or .show(), .save(), .crop(), .pandas(), etc.
```

To provide some context, here are a few details:

The input shape expected by the model is [1, 640, 640, 3].
The output details show that the output tensor shape is [1, 25200, 6].
The threshold used to filter bounding boxes is set to 0.5.
The model file, personK1.tflite, is compatible with TensorFlow.

This is exactly the input_details:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'serving_default_input_1:0',
        'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 640, 640,   3]),
        'shape_signature': array([  1, 640, 640,   3]),
        'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0),
        'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
        'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
        'quantized_dimension': 0},
        'sparsity_parameters': {}
    }
]
```

and this is exactly the output_details:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0',
        'index': 532, 'shape': array([    1, 25200,     6]),
        'shape_signature': array([    1, 25200,     6]),
        'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
        'quantization': (0.0, 0),
        'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
        'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
        'quantized_dimension': 0},
        'sparsity_parameters': {}
    }
]
```

Could someone please help me identify the potential issue with my code or suggest any possible reasons why the YOLOv5 model in TensorFlow is not detecting persons in the images?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

To troubleshoot the issue, I have already tried the following steps:

1. Verified the input shape: I have confirmed that the input shape I am providing matches the expected input shape of the model, which is [1, 640, 640, 3]. I resized the input image to 640x640 pixels to match the model's input shape.
2. Checked preprocessing: I have carefully preprocessed the input image by resizing it and normalizing the pixel values. I followed the same preprocessing steps mentioned in the model documentation.
3. Adjusted the threshold value: I experimented with different threshold values to filter out the bounding boxes. I initially set the threshold to 0.5, but I also tried lower values to ensure that the confidence threshold was not causing the issue

Despite these attempts, the YOLOv5 model in TensorFlow still fails to detect any persons in the test images. I expected the model to correctly identify and draw bounding boxes around the persons present in the images, similar to the results obtained with the Ultralytics YOLOv5 library.